# I'm installing Windows Phone SDK 8.0 and it requests packages?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-phone-8

I've tried installing Windows Phone 8 SDK on three different machines, all of which are fully updated to the latest patches on Windows 8. I keep getting [image]

It won't allow me to download the packages from the internet nor does it seem the packages are located in the path that is provided in the text box. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Some certificate on Microsoft's site expired and is preventing it from installing properly. Set the date on your computer to October 3, 2013 and run the installer again. Choose the "repair" option and it will install successfully. When installation is complete, set the date back to today's date.